# Java: How to count read bytes from InputStream without allocating the full memory before

Tags: java, stream, limit

I have a Java-backend where user can upload files to it. I want to limit these uploaded files to a max size and want to check the amount of uploaded bytes while the upload happens and break the transmission as soon as the limit is reached.

Currently I am using InputStream.available() before allocation for determination of estimated size, but that seems to be seen as unreliable.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Reliable or not, `available()` doesn't do what you're looking for. There is an explicit warning in the Javadoc *against* using it as the number of bytes remaining in the stream. That's not what it's for. Your problem isn't difficult. You can just keep track of the accumulated read count and abort when it gets too high.

Comment: Side note: if possible, avoid such a design. One should always strive for **fail fast** user interaction. Meaning: if you know that an operation will not be working, then fail immediately. Thus: if there is any chance that your front end code can be checking file sizes ... then you should failing right there before even starting the **upload** process. (of course, the ability to do so depends on your frontend, and you still need the backend checking - but your users won't appreciate a backend-only solution!)

Comment: Of course .available() doesn't work in here. I'd suggest to check Multipart Request file size _before_ you read the data with InputStream. Implementation of such lightweight validation depends on your backend implementation (netty, tomcat, etc?) Also, you could wrap InputStream by a decorator which extends InputStream and uses internal buffer like BufferedInputStream and has a counter of read bytes. Read buffer by buffer until the total byte count < limit. But again, you may spend time if the file is too long. Try to check Multipart file size before.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [Guava's CountingInputstream](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/io/CountingInputStream.html) or [Apache IO's CountingInputStream](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.4/index.html?org/apache/commons/io/input/CountingInputStream.html) when you want to know how many bytes have been read.

On the other hand when you want to stop the upload immediatly when reaching some limit then just count while reading chunks of bytes and close the stream when the limit has been exceeded.

Comment: The question explicitly asked for a way to get the number *before* reading the data. Knowing the number of bytes after you have read them, is trivial and doesn’t need a special 3rd party input stream.

Comment: @Holger You *can't* know the number of bytes without reading them.

Comment: @Holger Maybe you've read another question. `[...] check the amount of uploaded bytes while the upload happens [...]`. You cannot know how many bytes will be there before reading. The most you can do is relying on header fields but this is about trusting the sender.

Comment: @EJP: unless there is some protocol telling you the number beforehand. However, saying, “there is no solution” would be an appropriate answer.

Comment: @Fabian Barney: exactly, evaluating the header fields has its limitations. Discussing these limitations inside the answer would be a good move. But I’m quite sure, that real life servers will simply close the connection after reading the number of bytes declared in the header, instead of trying to guess the right number in case the number was not correct.

Comment: @Holger I haven't said there is no solution. There *is* a solution. Read until you have exceeded the quota. NB he says '*while* the upload happens', not before it.

Comment: @EJP: maybe, my interpretation was too strong, but from the OP’s misguided `available()` attempt, I concluded he wants to know it beforehand (preferably). In all other cases, the OP *has* to allocate some storage to hold the data and track the fill state of that storage (which is easy using the value returned by `read`). So I still don’t understand the purpose of these 3rd party references of this answer.

Comment: Of course, there is no magic in counting on your own when you do not like to use 3rd party libs. On the other hand I expect Guava or Apache being available in most projects. Nevertheless I expect the code to be cleaner and less verbose with CountingInputStream used. (Beside that it has advantages when the uploaded file needs complex processing where several methods are reading bytes from the InputStream. The counting by CountingInputStream cannot be (unintended) bypassed and you don't have to implement counting logic in each processing method.)

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to 'allocat[e] the full memory before'. Just use a normally sized buffer, say 8k, and perform the normal copy loop, tallying the total transferred. If it exceeds the quota, stop, and destroy the output file.

Answer (score 0):

```
int count = 1;
InputStream stream;
if (stream.available() < 3) {
count++;
}
Result:
[0][1]{2][3] 
 1  1  1  1
```

Answer (score -1):

If you're using a servlet and a multipart request you can do this:

```
public void doPost( final HttpServletRequest request, final HttpServletResponse response )
    throws ServletException, IOException {
  String contentLength = request.getHeader("Content-Length");
  if (contentLength != null && maxRequestSize > 0 && 
           Integer.parseInt(contentLength) > maxRequestSize) {
     throw new MyFileUploadException("Multipart request is larger than allowed size");
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

My solution looks like this:

```
public static final byte[] readBytes (InputStream in, int maxBytes)
throws IOException {
    byte[] result               = new byte[maxBytes];
    int bytesRead               = in.read (result);
    if (bytesRead > maxBytes) {         
        throw new IOException   ("Reached max bytes (" + maxBytes + ")");
    }       
    if (bytesRead < 0) {            
        result                  = new byte[0];
    }
    else {
        byte[] tmp              = new byte[bytesRead];
        System.arraycopy        (result, 0, tmp, 0, bytesRead);
        result                  = tmp;
    }       
    return result;
}
```

**EDIT:**
New variant

```
public static final byte[] readBytes (InputStream in, int bufferSize, int maxBytes)
throws IOException {

    ByteArrayOutputStream out       = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    byte[] buffer                   = new byte[bufferSize];

    int bytesRead                   = in.read (buffer);
    out.write                       (buffer, 0, bytesRead);

    while (bytesRead >= 0) {

        if (maxBytes > 0 && out.size() > maxBytes) {

            String message          = "Reached max bytes (" + maxBytes + ")";
            log.trace               (message);
            throw new IOException   (message);
        }

        bytesRead                   = in.read (buffer);

        if (bytesRead < 0)
            break;

        out.write                   (buffer, 0, bytesRead);
    }

    return out.toByteArray();
}
```

Comment: It is impossible to read more than `maxBytes` when your buffer’s size is exactly `maxBytes`. Further, `read` does not necessarily read all bytes, so you should be prepared for the case that you have to call `read` more than once.

Comment: And you don't need a buffer the size of the largest possible input. And you can't assume that all the data will arrive in a single read. It won't.

Answer (score -2):

All method implementations of read return the number of bytes read. So you can initiate a counter and increment it appropriately with each read to see how many bytes you've reads so far. Method available() allows you to see how many bytes are available for reading at the buffer at the moment and it has no relation to the total size of the file. this method could be very useful though to optimize your reading so each time you can request to read the chunk that is readily available and avoid blocking. Also in your case you can predict before reading if the amount of bytes that you will have after the upcoming reading will exceed your limit and thus you can cancel it even before you read the next chunk

Comment: You will always read the chunk that is readily available, and you will only block once to do so. Adding `available()` into the process is just a complete waste of time.

Comment: I disagree, I once solved performance problem by using available(). My reader was faster then writer and in a lot of attempts available() was returning 0. So I implemented a logic that if it is indeed 0 I skipped the reading attempt until the info was available. Plus you can allocate a buffer of appropriate size to read your chunk

Comment: You can't know how long to sleep for if you don't read while `available()` is zero. On average you will sleep twice as long as necessary. Blocking in read on the other hand will block for exactly the correct length of time.  Allocating a new buffer per read is not necessary, and wastes both time and space.