# limit size of requests with com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpExchange

Tags: java, inputstream

abusive users may attempt to send really large requests to my httpserver so while a "maxRequestSize" config would've been useful, I have yet to find a way of dealing with this. I also thought there might be a timeout option somewhere but couldn't find anything like that either.

`httpExchange.getRequestBody()` returns an `InputStream` but based on my research there's no way to determine the length of an `InputStream` without first processing it

Comment: If it's not already too late at that point (i.e. the framework has already read the entire request and your inputstream reads from memory), you could count bytes (e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/37678337/995891) and throw an exception when there is more than you like or the `Content-Length` header suggests.